# Encryption with BitLocker

Tags: windows, bitlocker

My pc started encrypting a Flash Drive and it was interrupted. Now the Drive requires a password I did not make it a recovery key I don’t have. The PC that was performing the encryption has also appeared to fail, and so it should be presumed I do not have access to that.

Comment: You have at least 2 different problems: The flash drive encryption issue, and the computer issue. Please limit each post to a single issue, and include ALL relevant information so that we can understand the issue as fully as possible and provide a good solution.

Comment: Regarding your flash drive: was there data on it you want to recover? If you don't recall the recovery key, you are out of luck. Bitlocker offers you multiple ways to save the recovery key and password when you begin encryption, and if you don't keep that recovery key safe, the data is lost. Period. The correct thing to do is to format the drive and start over.

Comment: I apologize for the separate issues but no it was a 0.2% completion when it was interrupted so I have no recovery key nor a password

Comment: If the encryption was interrupted, then the data is gone, nothing can be done.  The fact the PC won't turn on is an entirely different problem.

Comment: You choose the password and are given the recovery key BEFORE encryption begins, unless you are on a domain and the process is defined to run differently.

Comment: But, the problem remains the same: If you do not have a recovery key or password, there is no way to recover the data on the drive. And if the encryption process failed and will not continue, then there is even more reason: You must format the drive and start over.

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical way to recover a BitLocker recovery key or password.

The impractical ways involved supercomputers and large amounts of time (years).

So, unless you have access to supercomputers and years of time, and unless the data is worth the effort, the only option remaining is...

**Reformat the drive and start over.**